# Getting element which disappears after a period of time

Tags: android, appium

I am trying to automate a native Android 4.2 application. The application plays a video and if you tap on the video a SeekBar widget which can be used to rewind the video is shown for 5 seconds.

The problem I am having is when I tap on the video to show the SeekBar widget it disappears too quickly before Appium can to do anything with it. e.g. get the seekbar coordinates for example.

Are there any solutions to this which don't require modifying the application itself? Is it possible to force the widget to always show for example? Or are there any other ways?

```
// tap to show the SeekBar widger
new TouchAction(driver).Tap(0.5, 0.5).Perform(); 

// get SeekBar element
IWebElement seekbar = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
    .Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.SeekBar")));

// get its location. 
// here is where test fails most of the time due to SeekBar widget disappearing too quickly.
var location = seekbar.Location;
```

Comment: I would suggest to have the below workaround to achieve what you want:
1- find the seekbar and put it in a wait for 30 seconds
2- the code of findings the seebar widget put it in a thread and start it
3- click on the video
in this way you start looking to the seekbar before you click in a video and it will still continuesly check if its their until it appears